# Files process in centos

Tags: centos

I wrote a c program running on Centos 7, every 1 sec, it generate around 1k files. Another program move the files to other folder (but same partition, /home partition), read, process and delete it. After a few hours, /home partition is very slow, even stop both file generation program and file process program. If reboot the server, can ping the server, but cannot ssh in any more. The server go back to normal state only after hard reset.

For file generation c program, I always open, write and close the file, file process is written in java. Is it because any leakage of my program? but why /home partition very slow even after stop the program, only return back normal state after hard reset server. Or OS problem? What different between hardware reset and reboot? Why does it not recover after reboot?

Answer (score 0):

The file system problem fixed after upgrade os to centos 7.3